# nx appl used as host and remote at the same time

Tags: angular, nomachine-nx, angular-module-federation, mfe

i am using NX and it is fantastic but i am not able to find a solution for a specific use case in:

Framework: Angular

I create a monorepo and...

- I need to create an app as HOST (done)
- I need HOST consumes different REMOTE apps both in static and dynamic way (done)
- I also need to use HOST as a MFE so it is also a REMOTE for another app (i can't do it.. is it possible???)
- And... I need my HOST is a REMOTE too but, more specifically is a REMOTE for an HOST of another project not NX. (is it possible)

Thanks